# How to compute difference in days of previous rows value using difftime?

Tags: r

Below code creates data :

[image]

```
idCol <- c('1','1','1','2','2','3','3')
rowNumIdCol <- c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
stepCol <- c('step1')
step1Col <- c('30-12-2010:11.02', '31-12-2010:10.06', '01-01-2011:15.12','01-03-2017:09.00', '01-05-2017:09.00', '01-06-2017:09.00', '01-07-2017:09.00')
mydata <- data.frame(idCol , rowNumIdCol , step1Col)
colnames(mydata) <- c('id' , 'rowNumId' , 'step1')
```

I'm attempting to compute the difference in days by id between consecutive rows using :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
mydata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(DaysSpent = as.numeric(difftime(dmy_hm(step1)[row_number], 
                                         dmy_hm(step1)[row_number()+1], units = 'days')))
```

But error is returned :

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: invalid subscript type 'closure'.
```

To compute the cumulative difference between days by id can use :

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(DaysSpent = as.numeric(difftime(dmy_hm(step1), 
                                         dmy_hm(step1)[1], units = 'days')))
```

How to compute days difference between just previous row ?

I think I need to access current and previous row as part of mutate ?

Update : the number of rows per id are variable.

Comment: If there are only 2 rows per id, you could use `first` and `last` i.e. `mydata %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(ind = as.numeric(difftime(dmy_hm(first(step1)), dmy_hm(last(step1)), units = 'days')))`

Comment: @akrun the number of rows per id are variable, ive update question, thanks.

Comment: You can use `dplyr::lag` after you group by `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what results you were looking for, but I didn't get an error if I added `()` after the first `row_number`

also, threw in an `arrange()` just in case that matters

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
mydata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  # arrange(step1) %>%
  mutate(DaysSpent = as.numeric(
    difftime(dmy_hm(step1)[row_number()+1], ## this is where I added ()
             dmy_hm(step1)[row_number()], units = 'days')))
```

Comment: thanks but your code seems to return negative day values

Comment: your code returns negative day values, when it isn't returning errors. I'll fix mine...

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` this is can be done with `shift`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(mydata)[, DaysSpent := difftime(dmy_hm(step1), dmy_hm(shift(step1, type = "lag")), units = "days"), by = id]

#   id rowNumId            step1       DaysSpent
#1:  1        1 30-12-2010:11.02         NA days
#2:  1        2 31-12-2010:10.06  0.9611111 days
#3:  1        3 01-01-2011:15.12  1.2125000 days
#4:  2        4 01-03-2017:09.00         NA days
#5:  2        5 01-05-2017:09.00 61.0000000 days
#6:  3        6 01-06-2017:09.00         NA days
#7:  3        7 01-07-2017:09.00 30.0000000 days
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using `lag()` is better for this task:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
mydata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    DaysSpent = as.numeric(difftime(
      dmy_hm(step1), lag(dmy_hm(step1)), units = 'days'
    ))
  )
```

Also consider converting column `step1` to POSIXct from the start:

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    step1 = dmy_hm(step1),
    DaysSpent = as.numeric(difftime(
      step1, lag(step1), units = 'days'
    ))
  )
```